# Selenium Grid Error

Tags: selenium-grid

Has anyone seen this error in CentOS, when running Selenium Grid:

SEVERE: Could not find any remote control providing the '*chrome' environment. Please make sure you started some remote controls which registered as offering this environment.

thanks!

Comment: from the error, it looks like you don't have a client registered in Grid as *chrome. Is it in your grid_configuration.yml? Did you start the client with the correct name before you run your test?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you started the hub but didn't start any nodes?  You must start a node so it can run the RC Server needed to handle your client request.